# Gtk Separator in Table

Tags: c#, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

It seems as if GTK separators are only visible in a GTK table when using both the expand and fill options for both `x` and `y`. The separator simply disappears when using any other set of options. For the sake of design, I would like each row of my table table to look like

```
[label] [separator] [widget]
```

where `[widget]` can be anything (usually an `hbox`). Has anyone discovered a workaround to this?

Comment: Is the separator vertical? If so, you will need to expand and fill on `y`; what happens if you set both on `y` but NOT on `x`? Side note: GtkTable is deprecated in GTK+ 3; you should be using GtkGrid instead.

Comment: Setting on `y` and not `x` still causes the separator to disappear.

Comment: Is there `column-spacing`? I'm wondering if the separator is there but you aren't seeing it.

Comment: Using GtkGrid ends up solving the problem.